# I'm having trouble installing the 'Spring IDE' plugin in Eclipse, and I want to know how to solve this

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-ide, java-memory-leaks

I want to install and configure spring framework in eclipse. However, the installation process is failing.

The operating system of the PC I use is Window7, 32bit. RAM is 2GB.

I ran Eclipse (Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)) and clicked on help> Eclipse Marketplace.

I searched for "spring" but the Spring Tools 3 Add-on didn't show up.

So I clicked help> Install New Software again.

Write http://dist.springframework.org/release/IDE to Work with and press Enter.

Checked out Core, Extensions, Integrations. When I pressed the New button, an error occurred as shown in the photo below.[image]

I restarted Eclipse. This time I checked only Core. When I pressed the New button, an error occurred as shown in the photo below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Sometimes I see the following message in Details:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Boot UI Support 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE) requires 'package javax.ws.rs 2.0.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Buildship Integration 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship30 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
    To: bundle org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring IDE Core (required) 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship30 [3.9.9.201906180643-RELEASE]

I modified -Xms256m -Xmx1024m to -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m among the contents of the eclipse.ini file. But the result is the same.

How can I install the spring framework in eclipse?

Comment: Instead download spring ide

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Eclipse 4.6.3 and STS3.9.9 do not seem to fit.

I tried http://dist.springsourse.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.3 at Eclipse> help> Install New Software. STS3.7.0 has been installed.